# Google Hangouts Chat bot to send DMs via incoming webhook?

Tags: python, google-hangouts

Is it possible to set up [this simple bot](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/quickstart/incoming-bot-python), using an incoming webhook, but send the message as a DM (not a @mention) to specific user(s)?
My guess is no. But then how could I achieve this?

Right now, the message is just sent into the room in which the bot was added and I can't see anything on DMs in the [messaging docs](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/basic).

You can currently achieve this very easily in Slack by setting up a so called [bot user](https://api.slack.com/bot-users) and using their [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) but I would like to do this in Google Hangouts Chat instead.

```
from httplib2 import Http
from json import dumps

#
# Hangouts Chat incoming webhook quickstart
#
def main():
    url = '<INCOMING-WEBHOOK-URL>'
    bot_message = {
        'text' : 'Hello from Python script!'}

    message_headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

    http_obj = Http()

    response = http_obj.request(
        uri=url,
        method='POST',
        headers=message_headers,
        body=dumps(bot_message),
    )

    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now you would need their Space ID or webhook url in order to DM the user privately whether you use a webhook (like you did) or REST API. Unless you have this Space ID/Webhook you cannot message a user. One way of getting it, is to ask the user for their spaceID and store it. Either way, Google API hasn't given a way to retrieve a different Space ID then the current one you are talking inside of. This means, a bot can only message users its interacted with at some point.

The current Space ID value can be retrieved from the event JSON (event['space']['name']) and then using messages.create to send a new message to the user

```
service.spaces().messages().create( parent = spaceName, body = response).execute()
```

OR it can be retrieved from the url https://chat.google.com/dm/ --> space ID is here <---

Google has not released any way of generating your own spaceID for a specific user.

EDIT: In order to get the webhook url. See below: [image]

then copy and paste the webhook url into your code above. [image]

NOTICE: If you need, this webhook url can be manufactured using the usual url for google chat with their space ID as mentioned above and a key and access token in this format: https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/< space ID >/messages?key=A< key goes here > &token=< access token here > 
For info on how to get a key and access token, read the documentation provided here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: Even if I have the space id, I don't understand how I could DM someone using a webhook. What you're describing doesn't seem like a webhook to me, but rather the Chat API or something? How would I enter the space id in the https request body in my code above?

Comment: @fredrik In your code, you are relying on a webhook, which you can get through the instructions I added to my answer. But that means the DM between the bot and the human must have already existed in order to get their webhook. You can't message someone you've never interacted with as a bot sadly.

Comment: I already had this setup and was able to send messages into a chat room associated with the webhook (using the code from my question). What I don't understand is where to specify the space id in the REST call so that I would instead send a DM. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Oh I just read your last notice ... So you're saying I should modify the webhook url to include the space id. Ok, I'll try that.

Comment: Logan, do you know if it's possible to set up the key/token using a service account and avoid expiring tokens?

Comment: @fredrik My apologies on late reply. Yes I highly recomend using a service account instead of expiring tokens. It will save you a lot of headaches. Create a service key in your Google Cloud Platform/Google APIs and then download the JSON. Then anytime you call the API authenticate using the JSON credentials as follows:
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(serviceKey, scopes)
    credentials.authorize(Http())
        service = build('chat', 'v1', http=Http()) # use "service" in API calls: service.spaces().messages().create(spaceID,resp).execute

Comment: if you want to reference JSON key file directly by file name: ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(<JSON file>, scopes)
(btw --> scopes = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot)